Lost five commits with git
I accidentally rebased a branch that was five commits behind and pushed to origin using -f. The five commits where made on a colleagues machine that I don't have access to. How can I get these five commits back
I can obviously undo the rebase but the head is now 5 commits behind

As you can undo the rebase. You may want to try
"git reflog"
and then
"git reset --hard [commit before your rebase]"
and then try to find the lost commit

Does this answer your question? Git: restore diverged repository after failed rebase

You learned the hard way to never use -f but prefer --force-with-lease that guarantees that you will have the commits locally and will be able to recover. If you fetched before, have a look at the reflog otherwise, only your colleague (or someone else who fetched) will be able to recover the commits. Or, more difficult, the admin of the git server or through the APIs of the git server (like Github).

@tripleee I don't think this is dup of that question because in this case the commits (probably) cannot be restored locally.

Are you using a centralized tool such as AzDO, GH, GL, BB, etc? Each tool is different, but some expose remote branch changes. If you had a PR/MR on that branch you can likely find the previous version in the history also.

The question doesn't contain enough information to know one way or the other.

If we can't know one way or the other, we should not close a duplicate until we find out.

If you never fetched those commits, you don't have them and you can't restore them. The colleague can easily restore them by undoing the rebase-push by means of the reflog, but that's out of your hands.

to sum up other comments: if you had at least fetched the remote branches: check on your local repo git reflog origin/that_branch, you will find the previous commit. If you didn't have that: you will have to look for other sources. Most central platform have a form of "activity" view (for example: the "activity" screen on github), or an open PR/MR which will give you a list of changes on said branch. One last way is: ask a colleague to re-upload the previous version.

For more details regarding remote commits lost when doing force push see this answer.

To sum up the information from the comments:
If you had at least fetched the previous state of that branch: check on your local repo git reflog origin/that_branch, you will find the commit you are looking for in that list.
If you didn't have that: you will have to look for other sources.
Most central platform have a form of "activity" view (for example: the "activity" screen on github), or an open PR/MR which will give you a list of changes on said branch.
One last way is: ask a colleague to re-upload the previous version.

To prevent future mishaps: use --force-with-lease instead of --force.

you will know for a fact that the changes you reviewed on your repo (when comparing your rebased work to the origin/that_branch version) do match the remote state,
even if you inadvertently overwrite a colleague's work, you will have the guarantee to have a local copy of the overwritten commit.

You may use an alias to have a more convenient way to access that option:
git config --global alias.force-push "push --force-with-lease"

# usage:
git force-push
git force-push origin my_branch
# etc ...


It should be mentioned prominently, that --force-with-lease does not provide any advantage for users who use git fetch (and its disguise in git pull) frequently.

To compensate for what @j6t mentions, the alias should include --force-if-includes, e.g. forcepush = push --force-with-lease --force-if-includes.
